# Nodemon restart twice when change is made

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am using nodemon in order to restart the app when change is made. It works good however it restart two times and thus sometimes it is a bit busy to read data returned from server (like console.log) since its reloaded twice.

I am talking about something like this:

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Connected to db and listening on port 8080
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Connected to db and listening on port 8080
```

I am working with Atom IDE.

If this question is missing information, please comment and I will update in case its not fully informative.

Thank you for support.

Comment: [follow this](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/763)

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me was adding the -L flag.
`nodemon -L fileName.js`

Comment: This worked for me, was annoying because it would restart multiple times and sometimes, I'd get a port already in use error because of how quickly it would restart on each change.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Possible Solution:

I would start by looking into the set of files/directories nodemon is watching. 
It may be currently configured to watch two different server files which is why it would restart twice for a single file change. 
If this is true for you, the solution is as simple as changing your config in order to manage only one extension.

Comment: Its is not the solution you can refer this [link](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/763) to see what exact problem is

Comment: try to get solution and edit your answer @katie Mary