# Nodemon and babel-node restart multiple times

Tags: node.js, restart, nodemon, hot-reload, babel-node

I'm using nodemon with babel-node in development environment. 
I'm working on Windows 7 and every time I change my code, nodemon restart multiple times.

I searched on google and even in stackoverflow and github, the temporary solution is just: re-install nodemon: `npm i -g nodemon`. But after some minutes, the problem come back :(

I tried add `--delay sometime` and even re-install node.js but it does not work

How can I fix that? This problem slow down my work :(

Comment: Can you post your babel-node and nodemon configuration settings?

Comment: what you mean by this `nodemon restart multiple times` please explain

Answer (score 0):

if you mean restart by this

[image]

then here is your answer

we use nodemon for this work

> nodemon is a tool that helps develop node.js based applications by automatically restarting the node application when file changes in the directory are detected. nodemon does not require any additional changes to your code or method of development.

[have a look at nodemon docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

if not then
look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48505213/nodemon-restart-twice-when-change-is-made)

Comment: I did know what nodemon is and how it work =.= . My problem is after changing code, nodemon restart server again and again (nonstop) => my server can not be used. Something relevant to my problem but the solution not work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39917343/nodemon-babel-restart-the-server-multiple-times